# How to animate exit transition of FlutterActivity(flutter screen) from native Android side?

Tags: android, flutter, animation, native, transition

I have an android application in which i have embedded the flutter module by building aar of the flutter module.

I'm opening my flutter activity on a button click from my native android app. I'm using overridependingintent after the startActivity for the open transition and i am exiting the flutter screen programmatically on a button click(**flutter side**) using **SystemNavigator.pop()** but the exit transition is not showing which i have mentioned in overridependingintent.

How to animate the exit transition when i programmatically exit my flutter screen ?

Code for the reference:

Android Native side:

```
btn.setOnClickListener {
startActivity(FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine("engineFlutter").build(this!!))
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open,R.anim.close)
}
```

open.xml and close.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Flutter side on button press:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => { SystemNavigator.pop() },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

use SystemNavigator.pop(animated: true);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please check the documentation, which says `animated: true` only works for iOS. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html